# Can't figure out why my BST isn't being built correctly

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I am straight up new to pointers, especialy pointer to pointers. So I'm trying to figure out as much as possible about BST using pointers. Iv'e been doing research but most ways BST's are implemented that I've found don't have a function to build the tree by passing in an array of integers for the data values of each node.

I'm trying to use my build_tree function to iterate through an array as the tree is being built.

Sometimes any amount of numbers input that is over a total of 5 or more gets printed out as only a total of 5.

So if I input `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` then the results are

preorder: `1,2,3,4,5`

postorder: `5,4,3,2,1`

It cuts off extra numbers over 5.

And sometimes the results are very unpredictable. Memory locations get printed off sometimes as well. I'm aware I haven't freed any memory yet, but I will work on that once I get this issue figured out.

I appreciate any feedback.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct TreeNode {
    int data;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
}TreeNode;

void build_tree(TreeNode **root, const int elements[], const int count) {

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        TreeNode *temp = *root;
        TreeNode *prev = *root;

        if(*root == NULL) {
            *root = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
            (*root)->data = elements[i];

            (*root)->left = (*root)->right = NULL;
        }
        else {
            while(temp != NULL) {
                if(elements[i] > temp->data) {
                    prev = temp;
                    temp = temp->right;
                }
                else {
                    prev = temp;
                    temp = temp->left;
                }
            }
            temp = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
            temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
            temp -> data = elements[i];
            if(elements[i] >= prev -> data)
                prev->right = temp;
            else
                prev->left = temp;
        }
    }
}

void preorder(TreeNode *temp){
    if(temp == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    printf("%d\n", temp->data);
    preorder(temp->left);
    preorder(temp->right);

}
void postorder(TreeNode *temp){
    if(temp == NULL)
        return;
    postorder(temp->left);
    postorder(temp->right);
    printf("%d \n", temp->data);

}
void inorder(TreeNode *temp){
    if(temp == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(temp->left);
    printf("%d\n", temp->data);
    inorder(temp->right);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int intNum = atoi(argv[1]);
    assert(argc == 2 && "Usage: bst#\n");
    assert(intNum > 0 && "must be greater than 0\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "Enter %i integer values to place in tree:\n", intNum);

    int input[intNum];
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < intNum ; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &input[i]);
        }
    TreeNode *root = NULL;
    build_tree(&root, input, intNum);

    printf("Preorder: \n");
    preorder(root);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Postorder: \n");
    postorder(root);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Inorder: \n");
    inorder(root);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Program is working correctly now. It is just missing a function to free the memory in the tree. I will work on this.

Comment: first, The size of the array using the `intNum`.

Comment: You can make a visualization of the tree ,see if it is correctly built.

Comment: I did. I'm having issues wrapping my head around the pointers. It seems that my logic is correct though.

Comment: `int input[argc-1];` should be `int input[intNum];`

Comment: else block at `build_tree` need  `temp->left = temp->right = NULL;` after `temp = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));` Also `i <= count` -> `i < count`

Comment: Thanks. My output is still printing the first correct number followed by 7 memory locations still though.

Comment: Did you the following changes? `int input[argc-1];` --> `int input[intNum];`  and `build_tree(&root, input, sizeof(input));` --> `build_tree(&root, input, intNum);`

Comment: @MedaUser You need to tell us what changes you made. Please edit the question to add that as an update.

Comment: Ok I updated the code to the current state based of of the answers you guys gave. The output now is more clear as each order print is down to 3 output numbers now but It still is printing memory locations though.

Comment: `int input[input];` ?? `sizeof(intNum)` ?? `(*root)->data = elements[i];i++;` : `i++` ??  
┐('～`;)┌

Comment: sorry misread some things. Fixed it. Also I thought I needed the i++; there to incremented after adding the first node

Comment: `i++` does not need.

Comment: removed it. Still memory output

Comment: Why do you use `sizeof(input)` (`sizeof(intNum)`) instead of `intNum`?

Comment: I thought sizeof(input) would return the size of the array of data values that would be passed into my build tree function

Comment: I changed it to intNum like you suggested.My results are looking better now. But I am only getting 3 values for each order output. If I pass in `3,6,3,32,6,7,4,3` preorder prints: `3,3,32` postorder prints: `32,3,3`

Comment: `sizeof(input)` isn't a number of elements.
It's the number of bytes required on the memory.

Comment: Ah okay I have it working correctly now. Thank you.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect when there is the same element.